# Request a Digicert Secure Site EV SSL certificate from Azure Portal (or PowerShell) for use with Azure Application Gateway/App Services

Tags: ssl, azure, ssl-certificate, azure-web-apps, ssl-certificate-renewal

I'm trying to generate/request a new certificate from Digicert in Azure. I've been instructed to purchase the EV SSL cert from Digicert's Business tier. They call it Secure Site EV SSL, but I don't see where I can specify the certificate type either in the portal or through Powershell. The portal has a text field under the advanced certificate policy where it appears I would be able to specify this, but Digicert support has informed me that this can only handle the Basic tier cert requests. The Powershell documentation appears to have the same limitation.

We use Azure App Services behind an Application Gateway, so I think that I won't be able to generate a certificate signing request to request the cert from Digicert directly.

Is it possible to generate or import the Business tier EV SSL cert in Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot generate a CSR directly in Azure. Your best bet is to generate a CSR and complete the certificate creation on your local machine, then export this certificate as a PFX to import into App Gateway and App Service.